# Programmatically start/stop broadreceiver declared in manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that listens to incoming SMS after user has completed an "`action A`". This message might come after, say, 5 minutes. I have two options:

1) Declare in `manifest`. But then I don't want my `receiver` to be listening all the time. This app will be used, say, once a month.

2) Start/stop from code. But, suppose user closes app after making "`action A`". As I understand the receiver won't be able to fire up then.

Is there is a middle path? I declare `receiver` in `manifest`, but, start and stop it from program code.

Also, is it a good idea to start/stop `receiver` from `manifest` in `OnClick()` handlers of buttons. Everywhere else I saw, it being done in `onResume()` and `onPause()`.

Comment: save a value in a sharedpref, test when you receive a broadcast

Comment: @njzk2 Could you please explain a bit? Do you mean that it is possible and a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there is a middle path?

I'm no Zen guru, but in this case, yes. Register the receiver in the manifest, with `android:enabled` set to whatever you want it to be at the outset (`true` if it should be listening for broadcasts, `false` otherwise). Toggle that state in your Java code by calling `setComponentEnabledSetting()` on `PackageManager`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you think it is a good idea to do this toggle from OnCLick() listeners of some view as against onResume()/onPause()?

Comment: @deeJ: The code in my answer would make no sense to do from `onResume()` and `onPause()`. That's for `registerReceiver()`, when you need a `BroadcastReceiver` around while some activity or fragment is in the foreground from an input standpoint.